# ¿no me muestra por pantalla el siguiente arreglo de string?

Tags: c++, array

hola tengo el siguiente código y no se porque al ejecutar el programa no me muestra el arreglo,incluí la biblioteca string.h y aun así no me muestra lo que es el arrelgo ,alguien sabe como solucionarlo,estoy usando el operador ternario

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    
    
    int n1[]={0,127,128,191,192,233,224,239,240,255};
    string IPc[10];
    
    for (int i = 0; i <10; ++i)
     { 
      (n1[i]>=0   and n1[i]<=127) ? IPc[i]=="clase A":IPc[i]==IPc[i];
      (n1[i]>=128 and n1[i]<=191) ? IPc[i]=="clase B":IPc[i]==IPc[i];
      (n1[i]>=192 and n1[i]<=233) ? IPc[i]=="clase C":IPc[i]==IPc[i];
      (n1[i]>=224 and n1[i]<=239) ? IPc[i]=="clase D":IPc[i]==IPc[i];
      (n1[i]>=240 and n1[i]<=255) ? IPc[i]=="clase E":IPc[i]==IPc[i];
     }
    for(int i=0;i< 10; ++i){
        
        cout<<IPc[i]<<endl;
        
    }
    
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: las asignaciones se realiza con ``=``, las comparaciones se realiza con ``==``

Comment: @Joshin gracias ¿deberia eliminar las pregunta?

Comment: No creo que sea necesario eliminar la pregunta, la forma en que trabajas puede servirle a otra persona.

Comment: También puedes responder a tu propia pregunta con las correcciones y marcar como aceptada después de unas horas, de esta forma sabremos que tu pregunta tiene una solución aceptada.

Comment: Gregorio o Joshin, pongan la respuesta como respuesta, así gregorio puede marcarla como aceptada :)

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias,ya publique mi respuesta

Comment: @Joshin gracias,ya publique mi respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el error estaba en que las asignaciones se realiza con =, las comparaciones se realiza con ==

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    
    
    int n1[]={0,127,128,191,192,233,224,239,240,255};
    string IPc[10];
    
    for (int i = 0; i <10; ++i)
     { 
      (n1[i]>=0   and n1[i]<=127) ? IPc[i]="clase A":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
      (n1[i]>=128 and n1[i]<=191) ? IPc[i]="clase B":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
      (n1[i]>=192 and n1[i]<=233) ? IPc[i]="clase C":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
      (n1[i]>=224 and n1[i]<=239) ? IPc[i]="clase D":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
      (n1[i]>=240 and n1[i]<=255) ? IPc[i]="clase E":IPc[i]=IPc[i];
     }
    for(int i=0;i< 10; ++i){
        
        cout<<IPc[i]<<endl;
        
    }
    
    
    

    return 0;
}
```